# Get string length as two bytes

Tags: python

How can I get a two-byte length of a string:

For example:

1. `'foo'` whose length is 3 would give me:  `0x0` and `0x3`.
2. `'bar' * 100` whose length is 300, would give me: `0x1` and `0x2c`.

I need to prepend the two bytes (as bytes, not ascii) to the string before sending it out via a TCP socket.  The two bytes are used by the receiver as the length of the string being received.

Comment: Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42370436/edit) to explain more. Right now it is unclear regarding what do you want.

Comment: o.k. I explained what I am trying to do.

Comment: Seems simple to understand: each string must be lead by 2 bytes telling the total length of the string. However, what is the language?

Comment: I thought the tag tells what language it is for.  In this case, Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is pretty straight forward.  This function returns a `tuple` of the two bytes to encode the string length.  The most significant byte is first.

**Code:**

```
def strlen_as_bytes(string):
    return len(string) >> 8, len(string) & 0xff
```

**Test code:**

```
test_strings = (
    ('foo', (0, 3)),
    ('bar', (0, 3)),
    ('foobar', (0, 6)),
    ('bar'*100, (1, 44)),
)

# check all of the test cases
for test_str, expected_result in test_strings:
    assert expected_result == strlen_as_bytes(test_str)
```

Comment: this would return 0 for the first byte every time.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the htons() and ntohs() functions from the socket module to make it portable accross platforms, and use big-endian (network byte order) when sending integers over the wire.

```
n = socket.htons(len("bar"*100))
byte1, byte2 = n >> 8, n & 0xff
```

Comment: `len()` returns a python `int` object. There are no platform issues here and thus the `htons()` call is of no value in this case.